# save file changes in google cloud shell (am using linux - VM)

Tags: shell, ssh, cloud

I Am logged into my Linux VM via google shell.

I can create new file, `sudo nano filename`,

Once I edit I am unable to save changes. What's the command? CTL + ??

Answer (score 0):

I am saving with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.